# Quartz + Spring Batch in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, quartz-scheduler, spring-4

I'm trying to develop an spring application which have integration of Quartz and Spring Batch. For some reasons, i'm not able to run it properly and getting some compilation errors.

Code:

```
QuartzConfiguration

@Configuration 
@ComponentScan("com.concretepage") 
public class QuartzConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean methodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean() {
        MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean obj = new MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean();
        obj.setTargetBeanName("jobone");
        obj.setTargetMethod("myTask");
        return obj;
    }

    @Bean
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean(){
        CronTriggerFactoryBean stFactory = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        SpringBatchJobs batch = new SpringBatchJobs();
        stFactory.setJobDetail(batch.job()); // here i'm getting some compilcation error like "The method job() from the type SpringBatchJobs refers to the missing type Job"
        stFactory.setStartDelay(3000);
        stFactory.setName("mytrigger");
        stFactory.setGroup("mygroup");
        stFactory.setCronExpression("0/1 * * * * ?");
        return stFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        scheduler.setTriggers(cronTriggerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

Spring Batch:

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchJobs {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    protected Tasklet tasklet() {

        return new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
                    ChunkContext context) {
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        };

    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return this.jobs.get("job").start(step1()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step step1() throws Exception {
        return this.steps.get("step1").tasklet(tasklet()).build();
    }

}
```

The problem come on the following line

```
stFactory.setJobDetail(batch.job()); // here i'm getting some compilcation error like "The method job() from the type SpringBatchJobs refers to the missing type Job"
```

How can i run Spring Batch jobs using Quartz2 in spring boot? Any idea

Answer (score -1):

Spring batch Job need to be launched by using spring batch job launcher.

Please refer below link for exact details on how to do it.

> https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/batch/quartz-spring-batch-example/